# substitution method for recurrence tree

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

If one has recurrence function -

$$T(k) = 2T(k-1)+ \frac 1k$$

how can one determine the upper and lower bounds?

For upper bound, I try use 'substitution method' and drew out recurrence tree, illustrated below the first four levels (i=0-3)-

$$i=0:  \quad \frac 1k$$
$$i=1:  \quad 2(k-1)$$
$$i=2:  \quad 4(k-2)$$
$$i=3:  \quad 8(k-3)$$

I know height of tree is $log_2(k)$ and total cost per level is $\frac {2^i}{k-i}$. But how can I use this information to make a guess, to then be verified by substitution method?

Additionally, what sort of method could be used to find lower bound? Can I use this same recurrence tree to make a guess for that?

Thank you.